# What problem determination steps can I take to diagnose webpack connection problems in node.js?

Tags: node.js, webpack, https, webpack-dev-server, codeanywhere

I have a server process (LeanIX reporting dev server) that I want to run on Codeanywhere using node.js. The server process is based on webpack-dev-server. I can run webpack-dev-server directly and everything works correctly but when I run the wrapper it fails. The code for the wrapper is here:

https://github.com/leanix/leanix-reporting-cli/blob/develop/src/dev-starter.ts

however I am stuck as to how the wrapper process changes the execution of webpack-dev-server so that codeanywhere refuses to connect. Can anyone more experienced in node.js than I suggest somewhere to look next to try and diagnose the issue?

Comment: Please elaborate what the issue is. `I am stuck as to how the wrapper process changes the execution of webpack-dev-server so that codeanywhere refuses to connect. ` could be anything.

Comment: @madflow The link contains the wrapper code. It is using spawn but I am unsure of how that interacts with the Codeanywhere environment differently to running webpack dev server by itself.